# Alerting user to time sensitive events

Tags: android, user-interface, alarmmanager, android-notifications

First let me preface this post by saying I'm not a regular Android user.  Our products are for both iOS and Android and I have more experience on the iOS side.  I'm looking for advice on what the appropriate "Android experience" should be for a feature and how to implement it.

We have an app that presents a number of "events" to the user that will happen throughout the day.  Users are able to ask  to be notified a few minutes before one or more of these events happen.  I need advice on how should these notifications be presented to the user.

I think I understand how to use the AlertManager to notify an Activity or BroadcastReceiver when an event is about to happen.  The question is what should happen next.

We could then use Android's notification system (using NotificationCompat.Builder) to enter a notification into the system.  The problem with this is I think it is too subtle.  These are time sensitive events and the user needs to have their attention draw to the device when this happens.

The other possibility is to display an Alert Dialog to the user (and possibly a sound) when the event is about to happen.  I have this working when our app is in the foreground.  However, when the app is in the background (or possibly stopped), I'd ideally like to place the alert over whatever existing activity is active.  This doesn't seem to work properly.  Instead my app's main activity seems to be brought to the front and then the Alert Activity is displayed on top of this, but with a black background (despite the fact I use a transparent theme for the alert activity).

Here is some code for this:

```
private void createAlarm( )
{
    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), AlarmDisplayer.class );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( getApplicationContext(), 3333, intent, 0 );

    //getting current time and add 5 seconds in it
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add( Calendar.SECOND, 10 );
    //registering our pending intent with alarmmanager
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
    alarmMgr.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent );
}


public class AlarmDisplayer extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
        builder.setMessage( "Alert received xxx" );
        builder.setNeutralButton( "OK", this );
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
    {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

From the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.southernstars.skysafari.AlarmDisplayer"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Or maybe there is some other way we should be doing this on Android.  One model might be the alarm in the Clock app.  When the alarm goes off, the whole screen is taken over by the alarm.  This might be a bit heavy handed but it is a possibility.

Any thoughts on what we should do and how to do it?

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by displaying a dialog (this way you don't block the users view entirely, but instead just a message that needs immediate attention) ideally the dialog should be populated with the respective information of the current alarm that is going off. Basically when the timer goes off, send a message to a broadcast receiver and then display your dialog. Your dialog should have 2 buttons:

1. goes to your main activity to show more information
2. Snooze/ignore/cancel.

Also to ensure that you have your message... set your Broadcast Receiver to be registered in the manfiest and **NOT** programatically.

Comment: Jox,  Thanks for your thoughts.  This is basically what I've been trying to do.  The alert dialog comes up just fine if my app is in the foreground. However, if some other app's Activity is running.  When I start the simple Activity that displays the dialog, my why app swaps into view.  Is it possible to just have the dialog displayed over the current Activity?

Comment: You should not start an Activity to show your dialog, just show your Dialog from your Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: You can show a Toast from a BroadcastReceiver, but I don't think you can show a dialog.  AlertDialog requires a Context and BroadcastReceiver isn't a Context.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with notification system and use Text to speech to alert the user that there is new event which they can get more detail from the notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use the AlertDialog with Context that belongs to a service that controls your broadcasts. That is maybe clean in architecture view too.